# Atheros Wifi Adapter Won't Work After Updating Driver Software

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

Recently I updated my Atheros AR5B93 Wifi Network Adapter's driver from 9.0.0.173 to 10.0.0.336. I got my driver from this website: https://www.atheros-drivers.com/download-driver-nr-310-for-atheros-AR5B93-and-Windows7.html

When I updated the driver, it didn't want to recognize the wifi I usually connect to. I then had to rollback the driver. 
I ran a troubleshooter and it said something was wrong with access point or the adapter was wrong. I know the access point ins't the problem because when I rolled back the driver, it connects fine.

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any clues?

Comment: Fill a bugreport

Comment: @IporSircer The place said the driver was WHQL